# Why is it that the Quantised Dirac field spin has non-half integral eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, spinors, dirac-matrices

The z-spin operator is:

$$\sum_{\vec{p}, r} \frac{m}{E} u_r^{\dagger} (\vec{p}) \Sigma_zu_r(\vec{p})N_r(\vec{p})$$

For a state like $|\vec{p}=p_3 \vec{k}, s_z=\frac{1}{2}\rangle$, this operator returns an eigenvalue of $\frac{1}{2}$. So, correct so far.

However, any state $|\vec{p}, s \rangle$ is an eigenstate of this operator, because the "$\frac{m}{E} u_r^{\dagger} (\vec{p}) \Sigma_zu_r(\vec{p})"$ part always returns some number, which equals the eigenvalue.

1. I thought eigenstates of z-spin were required to have their momentum in the z-direction. Is it true that particles of any momentum are eigenstates of spin?
2. Can't "$\frac{m}{E} u_r^{\dagger} (\vec{p}) \Sigma_zu_r(\vec{p})$" equal non-half integers for some $\vec{p}$? So, can spin really be observed to have a non-half integer value?

Comment: What is $\Sigma_3$? Please do not assume everyone uses exactly the same notation as the one you are familiar with. Also, *why* do you think spin would have to be aligned with momentum (the thing that measures alignment is [helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics))) and can you give an example where this produces non-half-integer values? It's currently had to tell what an answer would need to explain in order to convince you that the answer to both your questions is "No" because you don't explain your reasoning.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. $\Sigma _z$ is the third pauli matrix copied twice inside a 4x4 matrix. 2. This is because, in Relativistic Quantum Mechanics, the spin operator used to be $\Sigma _z$ itself. That operator's eigenstates were $u_r(p)  e^{-ipx}$, such that $\vec{p}$ is aligned with the $z$ axis. However, in the QFT version, the alignment suddenly isn't needed. Why? 3. I calculated the eigenvalue and the result depends on $p_3$. It's not $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{-1}{2}$ for an arbitrary momentum state

Comment: @ACuriousMind I don't know how to write matrices in latex. Please just tell me in yes or no if my calculation was wrong, and if it's always 1/2 or -1/2 for any $|\vec{p}, s\rangle$

Comment: So, if the entire thing is supposed to be an operator, what states does this operator act on? If the $\Sigma_3$ just acts on the $u_r$ behind it, this would be just a number. Is $N_r$ some number operator? Where does the claim that this is the spin-z operator come from? (for matrices in MathJax, see [the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023/143136))

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, $N_r (\vec{p})$ is the number operator which counts the number of particles of spin labelled by $r$ and momentum $p$. This is how states get involved here. And that's why it's an operator. I'm talking about the fermionic states where one particle max is allowed in a state.

Comment: @ACuriousMind That claim is from Student Friendly Quantum Field theory, chapter 4. They discussed something called "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics" where the Dirac equation was assumed to have a Schrodinger equation-like interpretation. Within that framework, $\Sigma _z$ was the z-spin operator. It's the matrix with the two copies of the third pauli matrix copied **along the main diagonal**. Imagine a 2x2 matrix with $\sigma _3$ at locations (1,1) and (2,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that the $\Sigma_i$ here are *non-relativistic* notions! When you do $p\approx 0$, i.e. the *slow* approximation, then indeed the number there is always $\approx\frac{1}{2}$, meaning particles usefully approximated by non-relativistic physics indeed have $\frac{1}{2}$ for non-relativistic spin. In particular, each particle has non-relativistic spin $\frac{1}{2}$ *in its own rest frame*.

For fast - relativistic - particles this is just a bad operator that doesn't actually correspond to anything: It's the spin-z operator in a frame that is far from the rest frame of the particle, and that's just not a Lorentz covariant notion.

That this operator is also $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ when $\vec p$ is aligned with the $z$-axis is just a consequence of Lorentz boosts in the z-direction not transforming the z-component of 3-vectors like $\vec S$.

Comment: (I deleted an earlier answer because it completely misunderstood what the question was actually about)

Comment: So it's just that this opertator's eigenvalues, for moving particles, don't correspond to any actual spin measurement outcome. Thanks